# Stocks listing inside a Google SpreadSheet

Tags: equities, google

I would be interested to have all the stocks inside a Google Spreadsheet. The features would be the Symbol, Name, Country, Sector, Industry.  An example would be ABC, AmerisourceBergen Corporation (Holding Co), US Stocks, Health Care, Other Pharmaceuticals.

```
Symbol  Name    Country Sector  Industry
ABC AmerisourceBergen Corporation (Holding Co)  US Stocks   Health Care Other Pharmaceuticals
```

It seems clear that we can get that information for all the stocks with `GOOGLEFINANCE`, but check for `LFAP` and `ACB`. `GOOGLEFINANCE` can't get me the 'sector' and 'industry'.

How can I do that? Actually, I succeed to get that information, but not for all stocks.